# What's causing an Xcode 3.2 giving __unsafe_unretained error for FMDB?

Tags: ios, xcode, fmdb

I'm trying to get FMDB setup and working for an app using xcode 3.2.6. I was getting an error for:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *databaseName;
```

But I appear to have fixed that issue. Now I'm getting and error "expected specifier-qualifier-list before '__unsafe_unretained'" for this line:

```
__unsafe_unretained id _delegate;
```

Any insight would be great. Another option that's better and/or more compatible than FMDB is also welcome.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FMDB was updated for ARC support. Why are you using an old version of Xcode?

Comment: I had a feeling that was the issue. I'm currently using snow leopard. Xcode won't run on this OS. Aside from updating to Lion and installing Xcode4 do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @dcp3450: See if you can just update the version of clang used? I don't know how to tell Xcode to use an updated clang though.

Comment: Looks like I have a new mission: Figure out how to update clang. lol

Comment: @dcp3450: You could also just try `#define __unsafe_unretained` and see if that's enough to fix it.